# SQL/mySQL - Average of Differences

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to find the average span of first vs last birth of each family of 4 children in mySQL.
I have the following tables :

- family (id,last_name)
- lookup(family_id,child_id)
- children(id,first_name,year_of_birth)

I've used the following query but just wondered if anybody can suggest something simpler(**without using views**) in mySQL - if that's even possible? Maybe some formulas/tricks I haven't thought of ?

```
SELECT
  AVG(span)
FROM (SELECT
  family_id,
  MAX(year_of_birth) - MIN(year_of_birth) span
FROM (family
INNER JOIN lookup
  ON family.id = lookup.family_id)
INNER JOIN children
  ON children.id = lookup.child_id
WHERE family_id IN (SELECT
  family_id
FROM (family
INNER JOIN lookup
  ON family.id = lookup.family_id)
INNER JOIN children
  ON children.id = lookup.child_id
GROUP BY family_id
HAVING COUNT(first_name) = 4)
GROUP BY family_id) AS derivedTable;
```

Thanks !

Comment: when you do `max-min` you get one precise *span* for each family. what average do you want to compute? there is no average if the value is just one. maybe the overall average? or the span is the average of the three intervals between each two consecutive births?

Comment: and you're not using any `view`s. is this homework?

Comment: Correct. I want the average of the spans for each family (compute the span of each family then calculate the average)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on *interpretation* of the attribute names, this should be enough.
Test it before you use it in production, I'm actually guessing what the names mean.

```
SELECT AVG(*)
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(year_of_birth) - MIN(year_of_birth)
    FROM lookup INNER JOIN children ON child_id = id
    GROUP BY family_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 4);
```